# aws sam, Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource HelloWorldFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Original template

```yaml
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
```

Error causing template

```yaml
Resources:
  NewFunctionName:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
```

```yaml
Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

I have tried changing `HelloWorldFunction:` to `NewFunctionName:`. Additionally I have also tried to delete `HelloWorldFunctionIamRole`.

**edit** :

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app2

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app2
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints: 
        - app.ts

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Comment: What is the actual, full template that you use and which produces the error?

Comment: Its the exact same as the Node18 Hello World Example from the AWS Quick Start application except I have changed HelloWorldFunction to -> NewFunctionName

Comment: Which documentation? Do you have any link?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/using-sam-cli-init.html

I have also updated with the original template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the name of the function from `HelloWorldFunction` to `NewFunctionName`.  So now you must go through and change all the references that used to say `HelloWorldFunction` to `NewFunctionName`.

For example where it says something like:

> Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn

It is referencing the `Arn` attribute of a function that, as the error message says, does not exist.  It does not exist because you renamed it.  Change all the references to the old name, to the new name.  eg:

> Value: !GetAtt NewFunctionName.Arn